# Rails relationship with a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have a `user` and a `merchant` that have a relationship.  I need to store information about the relationship, so I am using => through `user_merchant_relations`.

1) Is my naming convention incorrect?  I've read some answers that indicate it might have to be `merchant_user`

2) Should I force the "join" / "through" table to NOT have a separate ID (e.g. only have the two foreign keys)?

3) In the relation table I reference a `program_id`.  A `User`-`Merchant` relation can only have one `Program` ... but `Programs` will belong to many `User`-`Merchant` relations ... what is the correct way to handle this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - The convention is that the models should be ordered alphabetically, so the name should be merchant_user

2 - It seems that with the logic you explained there will be no merchant_user with the same merchant and user at the same time, so you can skip the id. Remember to properly create the validations.

3 - It seems that Program has many MerchantUser and MerchantUser belongs_to Program

Comment: Thank you, Anezio -- #3 was easy if you looked at it the other way! :)